# Permission Set vaules not being saved when installed from an unmanaged package

Tags: permission-sets

I created a manage package which contained a few components, one of them being a permission set on Object Settings for Leads, Accounts, and Contacts. On each I object I made certain fields read/edit, and then added the permission set to my unmanaged package.

Then I imported the package to a secondary dev org for testing, and everything seemed to import successfully. However when I clicked into the permission set that came from the package, the read/edit access I gave for specific fields were unchecked. I made sure this was saved on the org where the package was created.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Standard Objects permissions do not carry over .This is a known limitation currently .

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kmm6AAA

You will need to either provide instructions to an admin or need a login to the subscriber org to manually add the permissions for standard objects .

Comment: I would view this as s security feature and not a limitation. ISV should not be able to alter permissions for objects they do not install. In our package I have a configuration page that the customer can use to add the necessary permissions to standard objects using VF and MDAPI to the profiles they want to. Makes it more purposeful than automatic